# i need to return UnAuthorized or an error code instead of null when the status is no success ASP.NET API

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, .net-core

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TasksValue>> GetTasks(string userName, string password)
        {
            var currentUser = await GetCurrentUserInfo(userName, password);
            string currentUserId = currentUser.Id.ToString();
            var credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domainName);
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials };

            using (var http = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                var mediaType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
                mediaType.Parameters.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("odata", "nometadata"));
                http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(mediaType);
                HttpResponseMessage response = await http.GetAsync(string.Format(Constants.TaskByUserID, siteUrl, currentUserId)).ConfigureAwait(false);
                //var result = response.StatusCode;
                string jsonData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tasks>(jsonData);
                    var finalResult = result.Value.Where(x => x.Status == "Open").ToList();
                    return finalResult;
                }
            }
```

I need to change the return when this case occur `(!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)` i cant return null because `finalResult` might be null too, so in need to return like a status or error code any suggestion thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetTasks(string userName, string password)
{
    //....some if goes here
    return StatusCode(401);//401 not authorized or some other http code

    //... if you are NOT inside a Controller class the StatusCode method 
    //will not be available. In that case use this code
    return new StatusCodeResult(401);//same as StatusCode method
    
    //...else return some list or result
    return new ObjectResult(myList);
}
```

Notice that I changed the return type to be IActionResult and I used the StatusCode call to generate a StatusCodeResult.

Also I wrapped the other result in an ObjectResult.

Basically you can return anything that implements IActionResult.

There a few "pre baked" status results as well but they are short hand for StatusCode(some code goes here).

- return Ok() ← Http status code 200
- return Created() ← Http status code 201
- return NoContent(); ← Http status code 204
- return BadRequest(); ← Http status code 400
- return Unauthorized(); ←
  Http status code 401
- return NotFound(); ← Http status code 404

Notice you will need to add a using statement for "using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" at the top of your file.

Also your project has to be a web project like

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

If it is not a web project you will need to reference at least 2 assemblies:

Assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions -> for IActionResult
Assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core         -> for ObjectResult and other "Results"

Here is a link to Microsoft documentation for [StatusCode Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.statuscode?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Here is the link to Microsoft doumentation for [StatusCodeResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.statuscoderesult?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: yes i am calling the get task from the controller

Comment: @someone as you can see you can return any code you want by using StatusCode

Comment: i tried your way but its giving an error "the name "StatusCode" does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @someone you need to add a using statement for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc

Comment: @someone you will also need it for IActionResult

Comment: What version of .NET Core are you using?

Comment: @someone also if the action is not in a web project you will need to add nugget packages mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @someone if you are not inside a controller when calling this you need to replace StatusCode for new StatusCodeResult(401)

Answer (score 0):

For this I would do something like this.

```
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<TasksValue>),StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetTasks(string userName, string password)
        {
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(new List<TasksValue>());
        }
```

In Ok : you can return your result.
For NotFound or any other action.
Need to use IActionResult.